# Passing environment variables through jar file which app uses

Tags: jar, environment-variables, docker, config

I am currently trying out on the docker link between my app and db containers. I've checked on my app container and environment variables are automatically set when I link the containers together.

What I want to do is for my config file, which is packaged into a jar file, to receive the environment variables and set the required values to it. Any advice or help?

[image: My environment variables in the scala app container to connect to MySQL database in another container]

And this is how I create a config file in my jar file to connect to MySQL

```
database { url="jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR}:${MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT}/mydb" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"}
```

Comment: Can you provide in some details of the environment variables, we are talking about here. Probably with some snippet.

Comment: Are you saying you want to update a file in your image according to runtime environment? That seems a bit backwards, as the file will be created when the image is created. You can pass environment variables to your Java *process*.

Comment: I am connecting my scala app to MySQL db using the environment variables as you can see from the above pic. Environment variables will set the port address from the IP address of the DB container along with the port 3306. The port 3306 is exposed from MySQL image before i build it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating the config file inside the jar could be quite overkill.
It think you have several choices

- read the config environment variable directly in you program

  - use variable either directly or generate the config file there
- create launch script (details of this depends of you guest os in docker how to do it; sh/bash for linux etc..)

  - that script can generate new config file from environment and put it on classpath before jar so you program sees it.

**EDIT: added example**

You can save this kind of launcher script on docker image which dynamically creates configuration before launching actual program.

```
#!/bin/bash

# some default values for testing even without links to other container
MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR=${MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR:-127.0.0.1}
MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT=${MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT:-3306}

cat << EOF > /opt/yourprogram/dbconfig.conf
database { url="jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR}:${MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT}/mydb" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
}
EOF

scala -classpath /opt/yourprogram  YourProgram
```

Comment: Do you have any sample Linux script I can reference on for the second option? I am not that good in script writing.

Comment: Added simple example. I did not know how you launch the program or what the filename should be but maybe you get the idea anyway.

Answer (score 1):

What I did is that I wrote the sh file in my directory /tmp/restcore-1.0-SNAPSHOT/bin like this:

```
  #!/bin/bash echo "database{url="jdbc:mysql://"${MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR}":"${MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT}"/mydb" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" }" > myconf.conf

  jar uf /tmp/restcore-SNAPSHOT/lib/com.organization.restcore-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /tmp/restcore-1.0-SNAPSHOT/bin/myconf.conf
```

After building the Dockerfile and running the sh file in CMD, I use cat myconf.conf to check the config file and I'll be able to see the environment set.